# URL rewriting and redirection

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I just finished my rewriting with .htaccess and everything works just fine.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule blog/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+)    post.php?url=1&id=$2
```

The only I want to avoid is the duplicate content... I've searched a lot on the subject and sadly found anything matches my needs.

The fact is, the rewrited address "blog/my-new-post-77" is also accessible by "post.php?id=77" and I don't want it to happen. So I would like to redirect every post.php pages to the rewrited rule.

Someone have an idea for me?

Comment: I think it should be `url=$1` in your rewrite rule is not? you missed `$` mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, add extra variable to your rewrite rule to check it:

```
RewriteRule blog/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+)    post.php?check=ok&url=$1&id=$2
```

And at the top of your post.php file, check for that `check` variable:

```
if(isset($_GET['check'])){
  if($_GET['check'] == "ok"){
   //it comes using rewrite rule
   //cut and paste all of your codes in post.php file to here
   //that is which codes are available when user view your page in desired way
   //don't redirect to rewrite rule again here, since visitor came using that rewrite rule to here. doing so will result infinite redirect and will show an error
  }else{
   //this visit is not used rewrite rule to come here
   //here you can redirect visitor to not found page or just show an empty page by putting die();
   //you can't redirect to post pages here, because you don't know what post(id) that visitor need to see
  }
}else{
  //this visit is not used rewrite rule to come here
  //here you can redirect visitor to not found page or just show an empty page by putting die();
  //you can't redirect to post pages here, because you don't know what post(id) that visitor need to see
}
```

Comment: was such a good idea (I slapped my forehead for not thinking about it) ! But sadly, it doesn't work. Still the content on blog.php?id=77 is accessible.
Thanks !

Comment: Because you have to move your all codes to where `//it comes using rewrite rule` has and put `die()` or something in `else` blocks

Comment: Oh I see, totally misunderstood the way you proposed me. So, if I understand well, an header:location should be placed in the IF and die() in the ELSE ? Sorry for the miscomprehension.

Comment: I edited it with describing what need to do in each places as comments

Comment: Well, thanks for your great help @Janaka, I will be trying it right away.

Answer (score 0):

post.php?id=77 -> /my-new-post-77 via the browser

/my-new-post-77 -> post.php?id=77 via internal rewrite

Is it right?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule blog/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\-([0-9]+)$ post.php?url=1&id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s\/post\.php\?id\=(\d+)\s
RewriteRule . /my-new-post-%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I tried it and still not matches. Forgot to precise, "my-new-post", as written in the rewrite rule, is a dba row which is called by .php?url=1. I modified it, but still blog.php?id=77 content is accessible.

Comment: you wrote about post.php. `my-new-post` must be a part of the script URL to catch it into new URL.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which matches my needs waaaay more.

```
if($data["url"]!=$_GET["url"]) {
   header("Location:http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/".$data["url"]."-".$data["id"]);          
}
```

This solution forces the post.php?id=XX to go to the rewrited location as we wanted and by the same time, encounter any manual url rewriting.

$result being the SELECT ALL of my databases rows.

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

I tested @Janaka solution, with your great explanations, and it worked tho.

Thanks everybody; Case closed :)